# Quill cassandra, codec not found error for an user defined data type

Tags: scala, cassandra, quill

I am using quill in my "play-scala" project as an cassandra driver. 
I have a table with following structure -

```
CREATE TABLE user_data (
    id int,
    name string,
    addresses list<frozen<dwelltimebd>>
    PRIMARY KEY ((id, name))
)
```

where ADDRESS is an user defined data type, as mentioned here -

```
CREATE TYPE ADDRESS (
    city string,
    country string
);
```

The code written to access the data from this table is something like this -

```
object UserTable {
  case class addresses(city: String, country: String)
  case class userData ( id :Int, name :String, addresses : Seq[addresses])

    lazy val ctx = new CassandraAsyncContext[SnakeCase]("user")

    import ctx._

implicit val seqAddressDecoder: Decoder[Seq[addresses]] =
    decoder[Seq[addresses]] { (row: Row) =>
      (index) =>
      row.getList(index, classOf[addresses]).asScala
    }

  implicit val seqAddressesEncoder: Encoder[Seq[addresses]] =
    encoder[Seq[addresses]] { (row: BoundStatement) =>(idx, lista) =>
      row.setList(idx, lista.toList.asJava, classOf[addresses])
    }


    def getUserData(id: Int, name: String) =  {
        val getAllDetail = quote {
          query[userData].filter(p => p.id == lift(id) && p.name == lift(name))
        }
        val result: List[userData] = Await.result(ctx.run(
          getAllDetail
        ), Duration.Inf)
        result
    }
}
```

On running the above code the following error is received, -

```
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [frozen<user.addresses> <-> models.databaseModels.UserTable$addresses]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:289)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:220)
        at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
        at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
        at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:100)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:100)
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayRequestHandler.scala:99)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
Caused by: com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.CodecNotFoundException: Codec not found for requested operation: [frozen<user.addresses> <-> models.databaseModels.UserTable$addresses]
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.notFound(CodecRegistry.java:679)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.createCodec(CodecRegistry.java:526)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.findCodec(CodecRegistry.java:506)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.maybeCreateCodec(CodecRegistry.java:558)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.createCodec(CodecRegistry.java:524)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.findCodec(CodecRegistry.java:506)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.access$200(CodecRegistry.java:140)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry$TypeCodecCacheLoader.load(CodecRegistry.java:211)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry$TypeCodecCacheLoader.load(CodecRegistry.java:208)
        at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3542)
```

Could not resolve the issue, A few pointers that I received are that,

```
I need to first create Java TypeCodec and register it with the cluster. Then also need to implement row-codec for quill just to make it compile.
```

from [this post](http://gitchat.org/getquill/quill/message/614779)

Could not understand on how to do it, Any help in this regard will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This worked for me:**

From Datastax Docs:

> By default, the driver maps user-defined type values to UDTValue
>   instances.

For the Decoder try something along the lines of:

```
  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

  implicit val addressListDecoder: Decoder[List[Address]] = decoder(
    (index, row) =>
      row.getList(index, classOf[UDTValue]).asScala.toList.map { a =>
        Address(a.getString("city"), a.getString("country"))
      }
   )
```

---

**This didn't work:** (but maybe I didn't try hard enough)

Theoretically you could also define custom codec, extend Quill's `CassandraAsyncContext` (or any of the available contexts) to be able to get `Cluster` object, and then register the custom codec this:

```
def registerCodecs(cluster: Cluster): Unit = {
    val codecRegistry = cluster.getConfiguration.getCodecRegistry
    codecRegistry.register(new LocalDateTimeCodec) //just for example
}
```

You can compose the codec from the existing "basic" codecs.

[Datastax Docs on custom codecs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/custom_codecs/#creating-custom-codecs-for-user-defined-types-ud-ts)